# How do i extract 'string' value from rvml code in the tag textpath? Not sure how to assign the entire code

Tags: vbscript, xml-parsing, qtp, vml

I need to extract 'String' value from 'textpath'. I tried assigning the below code to a string 'innertext'. and then used the code 'xmlutil.create':

```
innertext="<?xml:namespace prefix = rvml ns......"
set xml1=xmlutil.create
xml1.loadxml(innertext)
```

But this displayed an error of being incomplete XML.
 How do I extract SR....... assigned to 'string' in the tag rvml:textpath?

The VML code that is used to draw a web element is in the below format in a single line:

```
<?xml:namespace prefix = rvml ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" />
<rvml:textpath style="FONT: 10px Arial, sans-serif; v-text-align: left" class=rvml on = "t" string = "SR......."></rvml:textpath>
<rvml:path class=rvml textpathok = "t"></rvml:path>
<rvml:skew class=rvml on = "t" matrix = ".*" origin = "0,0" offset = "0,0"></rvml:skew>
<rvml:fill></rvml:fill… class=rvml></rvml:stroke>
```

Answer (score 0):

If xml processing is not recognized, try regular expressions, search desired text and use capture group to get the value needed

```
Option explicit

Dim re, test

    Set re = New RegExp
    With re
        .Pattern = "<rvml:textpath[^>]+ string\s*=\s*""(SR[^""]+)"
        .IgnoreCase = true 
    End With

    test = "<rvml:textpath style=""FONT: 10px Arial, sans-serif; v-text-align: left"" class=rvml on = ""t"" string = ""SR.......""></rvml:textpath> "

Dim matches, m  
    Set matches = re.Execute(test)

    For Each m in matches 
        WScript.Echo m.Submatches(0)
    Next
```